# Find word that it is included in the tags, and if yes, delete that tag (with regex)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have 2 html tags. But only the first tag has these 2 words: **elementor** and **widget**. So I want to find all html tags that has those 2 words, and if finds, delete the entire tag.

```
<p class="jopp">.elementor-widget-text-editor: nu (.Elementor-drop-cap-view-default) .Elementor  s  50px} .Elementor-widget-text-editor .Elementor-drop-cap-letter {display: inline-block}</p>

<p class="jopp">Sunt fascinat de cazuri legale despre artă.</p>
```

I try to make a formula regex, but doesn't work:

```
(<p class="jopp>).*\K(?:\h+(elementor|widget))(?=.*p>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<p (?=(?:(?!</p>).)*?elementor)(?=(?:(?!</p>).)*?widget).+?</p>\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p                                  # open tag
(?=(?:(?!</p>).)*?elementor)        # positive lookahead, make sure we have "elementor" somewhere after but not preceeded by "</p>"
(?=(?:(?!</p>).)*?widget)           # positive lookahead, make sure we have "widget" somewhere after but not preceeded by "</p>"
.+?                                 # 1 or more any character
</p>                                # close tag
\R?                                 # optional any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Find myself an answer

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<p class="jopp">).*(\b(elementor|widget)\b.*).*(</p>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Be aware that will match when there is **only** `elementor` **or** `widget`

Comment: yes, I see now. Anyway, is an alternative :)